# While installing using WUBI Kubuntu just reboots on boot

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, wubi

I've installed Kubuntu 16.04 with a Windows application called "Wubi", but when I boot into Kubuntu to complete the installation it shows me the pulsing blue Kubuntu logo for about 20-30 seconds and then my PC reboots. Does anybody happen to know the fix to this?

Comment: To avoid such issues do NOT use Wubi, ever again. Do a proper installation instead. Ubuntu is a full fledged OS, not a program to be installed from Windows.

Comment: @MichaelBay I strongly disagree: Ubuntu is a full-fledged OP that even can be installed like a program from Windows.

Comment: @dessert I have to lightly disagree with your strong disagreement. Wubi is deprecated and has been for years. Why it lingered in the ISO release after release baffles me but now that's no longer a problem because it was finally removed.

Comment: @MichaelBay There may be different forks, but at least [wubiuefi](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/releases) is *actively* developed, the last release for 17.10(!) dating back only nine days. Plus [hakuna-m](https://github.com/hakuna-m) cares about issues, see Terrance's answer below – dead looks differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the help from @dessert, we were able to find this for WUBI and Kubuntu booting.

The following steps were taken from: https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/issues/10

> After the first restart it should display:
>
> ```
> Completing the Ubuntu installation. For more installation boot
> options, press `ESC' now...
> ```
>
> There you can press ESC and then you can
>   select "Verbose mode" in the following menu:
>
> ```
> Normal mode 
> Safe graphic mode 
> ACPI workarounds 
> Verbose mode 
> Demo mode
> ```
>
> In "verbose mode" it collects more information for debugging but it is
>   also a workaround for some issues. In some tests, it worked in
>   "verbose mode", if default mode "normal mode" didn't work.

Hope this helps!